# Using Netlify environment variables with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I want my web app, that's built with Nuxt.js and Vue.js to access the environment variables that I added in the Netlify environment UI (setting menu).

When I run the local server I have no problem with my code accessing the .env file and retrieving the right codes.

But when I build it with Netlify, it returns undefined.

I have tried adding different prefixes to the env variables since I saw some people do this:

```
VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE
NUXT_APP_MY_VARIABLE
VUE_MY_VARIABLE
NUXT_MY_VARIABLE
```

I do not understand why the variables can not be accessed when the site is live.

If you're missing any information, let me know and I will add it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to add the env variable into netlify from the menu they provided to add variable

Comment: That's what I meant with the UI / Setting menu. Does not work though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this page can help you!
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env

Try:

```
NUXT_ENV_MY_VARIABLE
```

instead of

```
NUXT_MY_VARIABLE
```

I use Netlify and Nuxt together with dotenv package:

```
"@nuxtjs/dotenv": "1.4.1",
```

Comment: You, my good sir, are an absolute legend.
I didn't really expect anyone to react anymore.
But this completely solved it.
Thank you!